# Issue with applying light open sans font in my css

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have a big problem in css with the font Open Sans

The issue is that I wanna see a phrase in white color with (light) open sans font, instead it appears bold only when using white color ! However when I write the same phrase in black or other color it appears light.
Any ideas ?

here is the code in this link :

http://shrib.com/ILjxuPtM

Test it please, and tell me what's wrong.

Comment: I would suggest you using jsfiddle, here is your code on it http://jsfiddle.net/VS2a6/

Comment: I don't see any difference between two http://jsfiddle.net/j83Ev/

Comment: there is a big difference, see the black is lighter than the white

Comment: Please check the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360061/font-weight-over-a-font-face-not-working.  I had the same issue and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an article about font rendering.](http://blog.typekit.com/category/type-rendering/)

> CSS `color` is another factor. Varying contrast between text color and background color can significantly change how type looks. Lower contrast means that anti-aliasing appears more subtle — the graded steps from foreground (type color) to background are less dramatic.
>
> **Light-on-dark text tends to look thicker than dark-on-light**, so lower contrast makes an even bigger difference in these cases.

I guess you can simply use the `font-weight` property to adjust the font.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already used the font-weight 300 which is the smalest one, but still no results :s

Answer (score 0):

Anti-aliasing on Macs makes light text in Open Sans on a dark background appear bolder. You can adjust the font-smoothing options to something else than sub-pixel to avoid this.

I used Photoshop to stack a layer of dark text on a white background at 50% opacity on top of a layer with the same text, but light on a dark background. As you can see, there is a white fringe around the dark text, which should not be there considering they are equally bold.

[image]